# Getting the correct value from a multi-dimensional JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm currently building a meal builder where it will work client side for a better UX, and have hit a small bump.  The initial version had it so there was just one serving size per ingredient type, however after review my client has added a "toggle" in which allows the user to switch between a small / large serving size.

The JSON file builds up from a MySQL statement and is created via PHP which I then get this in JS and pass the data to my UI controller.
I have an array of the ingredient types (carb, protein, veg, sauce), I loop through these to get the relevant ingredients for that type, then display all of the titles via the .split and then just need to get the relevant ingredient serving data based on small / large or 0 / 1.

Example of the JSON for carb & protein.

```
// Function to show the meals in the UI
let showMeals = function(data, serving) {
    let types;
    types = DOMstrings.builderIDs;
            
    for(let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        let builderID, builderEl, ingID, ingTitle;
        builderID = types[i];

        let ingredients = 
            data[builderID].map
                ( label =>                      
                     `
                    <label for="${builderID}-${label.ingredient[serving].id}">
                        <input type="radio" name="${builderID}[]" id="${builderID}-${label.ingredient[serving].id}" value="${label.ingredient[serving].id}" class="hidden">
                        <small>${label.ingredient.split('^')[1]}</small>
                        <i class="icon fas fa-info-circle bg green" data-tooltip></i>
                    </label>
                        `
                    ).join('')
                ;
            document.getElementById(builderID).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ingredients);
        }
    }
```

I pass in the JSON data and the serving size (default is small as only protein / carbs allow for a larger portion).  Initially I thought of passing in what's shown in the example ${label.ingredient[serving].id}, I then tried ${label.ingredient[1].id} but to no avail so I know I'm missing something but can't think.  Sample of the JSON file below (have prettified it for easier reading).

```
{
   "carb":[
      {
         "ingredient":"10^New Potatoes",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":19,
               "weight":170,
               "price":"0.00",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            },
            "large":{
               "id":20,
               "weight":340,
               "price":"0.00",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"8^Spicy Rice",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":15,
               "weight":100,
               "price":"0.00",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            },
            "large":{
               "id":16,
               "weight":200,
               "price":"0.00",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"9^Sweet Potato Mash",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":17,
               "weight":170,
               "price":"0.00",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            },
            "large":{
               "id":18,
               "weight":340,
               "price":"0.00",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"11^Tomato and Roasted Pepper Pasta",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":21,
               "weight":110,
               "price":"0.00",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            },
            "large":{
               "id":22,
               "weight":220,
               "price":"0.00",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"7^White Rice",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":13,
               "weight":100,
               "price":"0.00",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            },
            "large":{
               "id":14,
               "weight":200,
               "price":"0.00",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "protein":[
      {
         "ingredient":"1^Chicken Breast - Plain",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":1,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"5.50",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"22^Chicken Breast - Cajun",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":42,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"5.50",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"26^Chicken Breast - Tandoori",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":46,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"5.50",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"24^Chicken Breast - Thai",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":44,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"5.50",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"4^Lean Beef Brisket",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":7,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"5.50",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"3^Lean Beef Meat Balls",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":5,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"5.50",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"5^Salmon",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":9,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"6.25",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"6^Sirloin Steak",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":11,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"6.25",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"2^White Fish - Plain",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":3,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"5.50",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"23^White Fish - Cajun",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":43,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"5.50",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"27^White Fish - Tandoori",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":47,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"5.50",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "ingredient":"25^White Fish - Thai",
         "0":{
            "small":{
               "id":45,
               "weight":150,
               "price":"5.50",
               "cal":null,
               "carb":null,
               "protein":null,
               "fat":null
            }
         }
      }
   ],
}
```

** Updated JSON re answers **

Thanks in advance,
Nathan

Comment: I should add that the protein is the only ingredient type with a price as that drives the cost of the meal and the macro values haven't been inputted by the client as of yet.

Comment: This is an awkward structure, especially the serving size array. But to address some of your question – Assuming `data[builderID]` returns the array of `carbs` if you are just trying to get the name of the ingredient you should use `label.ingredient` which references a string (your `label.ingredient[1]` call would give you the second character of the string). If you need the `id` you'll have to find it in the array returned by `label['0']` (`label['0'][1].id` for the object after 'small`)

Comment: Thanks, I can get the name of the ingredient fine using the split method on my '^' character, but I was just a bit stumped by being able to get the ingredient weight (in the second array).

Comment: Like I said, you have to get it from the array referenced by `label['0']`

Comment: You said "second array" but I only see one, which is `["small", smallData, "large", largeData]`, i.e. an array with 4 elements.  As mentioned this is an awkward structure.  You should only store things this way if you are forced to.  Can you change the structure?

Comment: Thanks for the input.
Ideally, I'd like to be able to call label.ingredient[serving].weight (serving would be small / large).
The structure should be able to be changed as it's generated via a PHP file which I'll give a go at re-writing now

Comment: I have edited  my question after quickly reformatting the JSON as I hadn't spotted that when outputting so thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: With the edited JSON you just posted you would use `label['0'].small.weight`

Comment: Never mind got it thank you.  What I was trying initially works now as it was an issue 

<label for="${builderID}-${label[0][servingSize].id}">
 <input type="radio" name="${builderID}[]" id="${builderID}-${label[0][servingSize].id}" value="${label[0][servingSize].id}" class="hidden">
         <small>${label.ingredient.split('^')[1]} - ${label[0][servingSize].weight}g</small>
 <i class="icon fas fa-info-circle bg green" data-tooltip></i>
</label>